# How can I overcome Laravel 8 template system problem

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In layout folder I have a file named **"app.blade.php".** To render some content from other balde file I wrote in the file
`@yield('content')`

I created another file in **"views/admin"** name **"dashboard.blade.php"**. Written code in this file is

```php
@extends('home')
@section('content')
    Test text
@endsection
```

But content doesn't load in **"app.blade.php"** file thus nothing in

```php
@yield('content') section
```

What to do?

Comment: You can check my answer. Let me know about the updates. If you found the answer is helpful then don't forget to accept my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us your 'layout.app' file? There is something going on there

Answer (score 0):

update this

```php
@extends('layouts.app')  <---------- it will extend app.blade.php  then inside that section will render content
@section('content')
    Test text
@endsection
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#extending-a-layout

Comment: I wrote it by mistake. Writing like you has same output

Answer (score 0):

## Error Identified and solved

You said that content does not load in app.blade.php but you have extends the home page.

Update your script like this->

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
Test text
@endsection
```

I think you got where you made the wrong. Let me know about the updates

Comment: I wrote it by mistake. Writing like you has same output

Comment: Would you propose those files then it will be better to understand where is the actual problem you have been made?. Because this script looks fine.